# Como acceder a una variable global desde un fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio

Cordial saludo,

Tengo estas variables globales en una clase de java:

```
package com.windroid.dinas;

import android.app.Application;

public class GlobalVariables extends Application {

    private String Name;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    private String Usr;

    public String getUsr() {
        return Usr;
    }

    public void setUsr(String usr) {
        Usr = usr;
    }
}
```

Y este es mi fragment:

```
package com.windroid.dinas;

import ...


public class PedidoFragment extends Fragment{

    final static String urlAddress="http://10.0.3.2/baradm/ubica.php?id=";

    GlobalVariables globalVariables;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pedido, container, false);
        final Spinner spinnerUbica = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spUbica);
        /* <--- urlAddress+globalvariables.getUsr() --->*/
        new Downloader(getActivity(),urlAddress,spinnerUbica).execute();  

        return view;
    }

}
```

Y necesito que la parte:

```
new Downloader(getActivity(),urlAddress,spinnerUbica).execute();
```

quedara algo como asi:

```
new Downloader(getActivity(),urlAddress+globalvariables.getUsr(),spinnerUbica).execute();
```

Pero la variable getUsr da null, pero desde otras actividades si posee un valor asignado. ¿Que debo hacer para acceder al valor guardado en esta variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pongo un código que debería funcionarte pero te recomiendo que guardes estas variables en `SharedPreferences` por ejemplo.

```
package com.windroid.dinas;

import android.app.Application;

public class GlobalVariables extends Application {

    private static String Name;

    public static String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public static void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    private static String Usr;

    public static String getUsr() {
        return Usr;
    }

    public static void setUsr(String usr) {
        Usr = usr;
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.windroid.dinas;

import ...


public class PedidoFragment extends Fragment{

    final static String urlAddress="http://10.0.3.2/baradm/ubica.php?id=";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pedido, container, false);
        final Spinner spinnerUbica = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spUbica);
        /* <--- urlAddress+GlobalVariables.getUsr() --->*/
        new Downloader(getActivity(),urlAddress,spinnerUbica).execute();  

        return view;
    }

}
```

---

```
new Downloader(getActivity(),urlAddress+Globalvariables.getUsr(),spinnerUbica).execute();
```

Comment: Gracias funciono, aunque no se porque no son buenas practicas.